# Spring Social with Spring Boot not getting user email id

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I am new as developer, trying hands on Spring social facebook integration. Followed [this link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-facebook/#_fetch_facebook_data)

I am getting data like user's name', 'gender', 'locale'. Which can be given as constructor value to User class(see [took help](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social-facebook/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/social/facebook/api/User.html)).

But I want to get user "email-id", somehow that's not  possible the way i am getting data for 'name', 'locale' and 'gender.

We need to use method `getEmail()` as per docs. But I am not able to do it.
("A simple app with OAuth security implemented")

Here is the snippet....
My controller class code is

```
@Controller
        @RequestMapping("/")
        public class HelloController {

            private Facebook facebook;
            private ConnectionRepository connectionRepository;

            public HelloController(Facebook facebook, ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
                this.facebook = facebook;
                this.connectionRepository = connectionRepository;
            }

            @GetMapping
            public String helloFacebook(Model model) {
                if (connectionRepository.findPrimaryConnection(Facebook.class) == null) {
                    return "redirect:/connect/facebook";
                }


                String [] fields = {"name", "gender", "locale"};
                User userProfile = facebook.fetchObject("me", User.class, fields);
                model.addAttribute("feed", userProfile);

                //String email = facebook.getEmail();  
    /*this above one "facebook.getEmail()" gives Internal server error 500 */


                return "hello";
            } 
        }
```

Model class is ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Hello, <span th:text="${feed.name}">Some User</span>!</h3>
        <h4>Your gender is : <span th:text="${feed.gender}"></span></h4>
        <h4>Your locale is : <span th:text="${feed.locale}"></span></h4>
        <h4>Your email is : <span th:text="${feed.getEmail()}"></span></h4>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Main class is as...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}


    Any help is appreciated. Thanks.
```